# Выход за пределы двумерного массива

Tags: java

Условие задачи: дано число `N`, `N` меньше 100 . Создайте массив `N × N` и заполните его по следующим правилам:

- числа на диагонали, идущей из правого верхнего в левый нижний угол, равны 1;
- числа, стоящие выше этой диагонали, равны 0;
- числа, стоящие ниже этой диагонали, равны 2.

Код:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class prog {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int j = 0, i = 0;
        int n = s.nextInt();
        int[][] matrix;
        matrix = new int[n][n];
        while (i < n) {
            i++;
            while (j < n) {
                j++;
                if (i + j == n - 1) {
                    matrix[n][j] = 1;
                }
                if (i + j < n - 1) {
                    matrix[n][j] = 2;
                }
                if (i + j > n - 1) {
                    matrix[n][j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + ' ');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Происходит выход за пределы массива в этих строках:

```
if (i + j < n - 1) {
    matrix[n][j] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы объясните, что вы пытаетесь сделать. У вас все подобные предложения, как это matrix[n][j] = 1; некорректные.

Comment: вот условие задачи http://informatics.mccme.ru/mod/statements/view.php?id=282#1

Comment: Тогда как сделать их корректными?

Comment: Не надо давать ссылки. Приведите условие задачи в своем вопросе.

Comment: Берите отладчик, листок в клеточку и ручку и смотрите что у вас куда пишется...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Индексы в массивах начинаются с 0. Поэтому допустимый диапазон корректных индексов для вашего массива - это `[0, n-1]`

Для этой задачи лучше использовать `for` цикл.

Например

```
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
{
    for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ ) 
    {
        if ( i + j == n - 1 ) matrix[i][j] = 1;
        else if ( i + j < n - 1 ) matrix[i][j] = 0;
        else matrix[i][j] = 2;
    }
}
```

Что касается вашего кода, то у вас индексы начинаются, фактически, с 1,

```
while (i < n) {
    i++;
    ^^^^
    while (j < n) {
        j++;
        ^^^^
```

и в предложениях, подобному этому

```
matrix[n][j] = 1;
```

вы используете значение `n` которое находится за пределами допустимых значений для индекса.

Кроме того данное условие в if-предложении

```
        if (i + j < n-1 ) {
            matrix[n][j] = 2;
        }
```

это условие для элементов массива, расположенных выше побочной диагонали. Они должны быть заполнены 0 согласно вашему же описанию, а не 2.

Answer (score 2):

Вы объявляете массив n*n:

```
matrix = new int[n][n];
```

При объявлении счёт начинается с единицы. Ну, логично, не будете же вы массив 1*1 объявлять, как `int[0][0]`.

А потом вы пытаетесь получить доступ к `n`-му элементу массива, в котором максимальный элемент - `n-1`:

```
matrix[n][j] = 0;
```

Конечно, получите выход за пределы.

Вы проверяете, не выходит ли j за границы размера

```
while (j < n)
```

А потом берёте и выходите за границы.

```
j++;
```

Не надо делать такие вещи...